# Exporting Gridview table to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, export, datagridviewcolumn

im exporting a gridview table to Microsoft Excel using this code :

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Visible= true;
        ws.Cells[1, 1] = "VehiclePlateNumber";
        ws.Cells[1, 2] = "VehicleDescription";
        ws.Cells[1, 3] = "Distance";

        for (int j = 2; j <= datagridview1.Rows.Count; j++)
        {

            for (int i = 2; i <= 3; i++)

            {
                ws.Cells[j, i] = datagridview1.Rows[j - 2].Cells[i - 1].Value;
            }

}
```

its working, but the first column is showing only the header text without data, i dont know what is the problem, and i tried to do some changes to the code but i couldn't reach the solution, any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

They way you set the for loops results in looping only in two colums (`i=2 ;i<=3`) and you also miss the final row.
Also in your code you are missing a closing parenthesis.

Try:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < datagridview1.Rows.Count; j++)
        {   
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)  
            {
                ws.Cells[j, i+1] = datagridview1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: it gives me error when i press the button,the error says : 

COM exception was unhandled
Exception from HARESULT 0X800A03EC

Answer (score 0):

I think apomene is almost right.

`ws.Cells[j +1 , i+1] = datagridview1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value;`

As for some reason excel is not zero based. The only difference is +1 after the j.

Comment: after i used your code, i got all the data right, but all of the header text columns gone,why im facing this :/

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved after using this code  :

```
for (int j = 2; j <= datagridview1.Rows.Count; j++)
{
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
ws.Cells[j, i] = datagridview1.Rows[j - 2].Cells[i - 1].Value;
}
}
}
```